# Binary Thread Scheduler

Tags: performance, c, multithreading

The term, I used, *binary thread scheduler* means a scheduler that orders the execution of two threads for two tasks that has a specific dependency. Rather than using some mathematical expressions to explain this, think about scheduling two threads for double buffering. Thread 1 ends writing in buffer 1 and signals thread 2 that it can read buffer 1. Now thread 1 and 2 can run in parallel. If thread 2 ends reading buffer 1 before thread 1 has not finished writing in buffer 2, it has to wait for thread 1 to finish, and so on. I tried implemented such a scheduler with minimum overhead possible.

Before reading the code, I recommend running it first and see how each *state* is encoded. Rather than me trying to explain the pattern, I think you'll be quicker to catch the pattern by actually looking at the output of each state before a task has been done.

Sorry for the short variable names, but that's what I prefer when writing my own code. Somehow it's less confusing with short names when following the code to verify the algorithm.

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef _Atomic int binSched_t;

#define astr_(a, b) atomic_store_explicit(a, b, memory_order_relaxed)
#define aldr_(a) atomic_load_explicit(a, memory_order_relaxed)
#define acmpxchgr_(a, b, c) atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(a, b, c,\
memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed)
#define bsch_state_(i) (1 << (i))

static void bsch_init(binSched_t *_) {
    astr_(_, bsch_state_(2));
}

static int bsch_recv0(binSched_t *_) {
    int s;
    while (!(s = aldr_(_) & 055));
    return s > bsch_state_(2);
}

static void bsch_send0(binSched_t *_, int t) {
    if (t) {
        int s = bsch_state_(3);
        if (!acmpxchgr_(_, &s, bsch_state_(4))) {
            astr_(_, bsch_state_(0));
        }
    } else {
        int s = bsch_state_(0);
        if (!acmpxchgr_(_, &s, bsch_state_(1))) {
            astr_(_, bsch_state_(3));
        }
    }
}

static int bsch_recv1(binSched_t *_) {
    int s;
    while (!(s = aldr_(_) & 033));
    return s < bsch_state_(2);
}

static void bsch_send1(binSched_t *_, int t) {
    if (t) {
        int s = bsch_state_(0);
        if (!acmpxchgr_(_, &s, bsch_state_(2))) {
            astr_(_, bsch_state_(3));
        }
    } else {
        int s = bsch_state_(3);
        if (!acmpxchgr_(_, &s, bsch_state_(5))) {
            astr_(_, bsch_state_(0));
        }
    }
}

static binSched_t bs;

static void printState() {
    static const char *const s[] = {
        "0 2\n2 0\n",
        "2 1\n1 0\n",
        "0 1\n1 2\n",
        "2 0\n0 2\n",
        "1 2\n0 1\n",
        "1 0\n2 1\n"
    };
    switch (aldr_(&bs)) {
        case bsch_state_(0): puts(s[0]); break;
        case bsch_state_(1): puts(s[1]); break;
        case bsch_state_(2): puts(s[2]); break;
        case bsch_state_(3): puts(s[3]); break;
        case bsch_state_(4): puts(s[4]); break;
        case bsch_state_(5): puts(s[5]); break;
        default: __builtin_unreachable();
    }
}

static void *main2(void *_) {
    for (;;) {
        int t = bsch_recv1(&bs);
        printf("thread 2 task %d\n", t + 1);
        printState();
        bsch_send1(&bs, t);
    }
    return _;
}

int main() {
    bsch_init(&bs);
    pthread_t th;
    pthread_create(&th, NULL, main2, NULL);
    for (;;) {
        int t = bsch_recv0(&bs);
        printf("thread 1 task %d\n", t + 1);
        printState();
        bsch_send0(&bs, t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The reason I wrote this was to minimize the overhead when there is no need to wait, that is when the thread can acquire the lock immediately. In my tests, spinlocks do have the minimal overhead in such cases. However minimal waiting time does not necessarily mean fastest overall throughput. Actually the original implementation has a slightly worse throughput than an alternative implementation using semaphores. Semaphores have a larger base overhead having to deal with the kernel, but they don't mess up with the OS scheduler like spinlocks. Unless the important thread which is doing something is a realtime thread, the OS thinks the busy-waiting thread is also important, so the job-doing thread occasionally gets blocked because of the busy-waiting thread.

I also tested a version with Posix condition variables. They have a surprisingly low overhead to acquire the lock. Even faster than a spinlock! But the overall throughput is worse than both the semaphore and the spinlock version.

- Throughput

  - Semaphore > Spinlock > Condition Variable
- Lock Overhead

  - Semaphore > Spinlock > Condition Variable
- Stability

  - Condition Variable > Semaphore > Spinlock

This is the semaphore version.

```
static void chk(int ok) {
    if (!__builtin_expect(ok, true)) abort();
}

typedef struct {
    sem_t *p[2];
    sem_t s[2][2];
} binSched_t;

static void bsch_init(binSched_t *_) {
    *_->p = *_->s;
    _->p[1] = _->s[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            chk(!sem_init(_->s[i] + j, false, !i));
        }
    }
}

static int bsch_recv0(binSched_t *_) {
    chk(!sem_wait(*_->p));
    return *_->p == *_->s + 1;
}

static void bsch_send0(binSched_t *_, int t) {
    chk(!sem_post(*_->p + 2));
    *_->p = *_->s + !t;
}

static int bsch_recv1(binSched_t *_) {
    chk(!sem_wait(_->p[1]));
    return _->p[1] == _->s[1] + 1;
}

static void bsch_send1(binSched_t *_, int t) {
    chk(!sem_post(_->p[1] - 2));
    _->p[1] = _->s[1] + !t;
}
```

And this is the condition variable version.

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t m;
    int f;
    pthread_cond_t _;
} cond_t;

typedef struct {
    cond_t *p[2];
    cond_t c[2][2];
} binSched_t;

static void bsch_init(binSched_t *_) {
    *_->p = *_->c;
    _->p[1] = _->c[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            cond_t *c = _->c[i] + j;
            chk(!pthread_mutex_init(&c->m, NULL));
            c->f = !i;
            chk(!pthread_cond_init(&c->_, NULL));
        }
    }
}

static int bsch_recv0(binSched_t *_) {
    cond_t *c = *_->p;
    chk(!pthread_mutex_lock(&c->m));
    if (!c->f) chk(!pthread_cond_wait(&c->_, &c->m));
    c->f = false;
    chk(!pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->m));
    return c == *_->c + 1;
}

static void bsch_send0(binSched_t *_, int t) {
    cond_t *c = *_->p + 2;
    chk(!pthread_mutex_lock(&c->m));
    c->f = true;
    chk(!pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->m));
    chk(!pthread_cond_signal(&c->_));
    *_->p = *_->c + !t;
}

static int bsch_recv1(binSched_t *_) {
    cond_t *c = _->p[1];
    chk(!pthread_mutex_lock(&c->m));
    if (!c->f) chk(!pthread_cond_wait(&c->_, &c->m));
    c->f = false;
    chk(!pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->m));
    return c == _->c[1] + 1;
}

static void bsch_send1(binSched_t *_, int t) {
    cond_t *c = _->p[1] - 2;
    chk(!pthread_mutex_lock(&c->m));
    c->f = true;
    chk(!pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->m));
    chk(!pthread_cond_signal(&c->_));
    _->p[1] = _->c[1] + !t;
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw I left the original code and the explanation as is, and split the additional info and the other versions with a horizontal bar, so nothing in the current answer is invalidated.

Answer (score 5):

This answer only addresses the original spinlock version in the question.

## Ensure the code is self-explanatory

> Before reading the code, I recommend running it first and see how each state is encoded. Rather than me trying to explain the pattern, I think you'll be quicker to catch the pattern by actually looking at the output of each state before a task has been done.

This is Code Review, not Program Output Review. If you need to run the code and analyze its output to understand what the program is doing, that is a problem. The code should ideally be self-explanatory; either C code itself should make it clear what the pattern is, or there should be comments added to the code to explain it.

## Use clear and descriptive function and variable names

> Sorry for the short variable names, but that's what I prefer when writing my own code.

That may be the case when *writing* your code, but for me reading it, it makes it very incomprehensible. And that probably means that it will also become incomprehensible for you in a year's time, when you have been working on other things and all the abbreviations you have used here are no longer clear in your mind.

To ensure your code is maintainable by both you and others, I strongly recommend that you give functions and variables names that are clear and descriptive. Don't abbreviate unnecessarily.

If you are going to abbreviate something, be consistent. I can understand you don't want to write `binary_scheduler` everywhere, but then either pick `bsch` or `binSched` and use it consistently.

Prefer using verbs for functions and nouns for variables.

## Avoid using macros

Don't use macros if you can use a regular function. For example:

```
static void astr_(volatile binSched_t *a, binSched_t b) {
    atomic_store_explicit(a, b, memory_order_relaxed);
}
...
static int bsch_state_(int i) {
    return 1 << (i - 1);
}
```

## Use an `enum` to give names to the states

Only after reading the whole code can I be sure that there are six states, numbered from 1 to 6. I still have to follow all the code paths to be able to understand what a given state means. And this is a very simple program, consider what happens in a more complex program where you have many more states?

Create an `enum` to give names to each state, and use those names consistently.

## Avoid busy-loops

In your receive functions, you are repeatedly checking an atomic variable and waiting for it to have a certain value. This will keep the CPU busy unnecessarily, using more power, increasing its temperature and shortening battery life if you are running this on a laptop or phone for example.

I recommend that instead of using atomics manually, you should use a mutex and a condition variable to synchronize the threads. These are much simpler to reason about and are quite efficient.

They are efficient because in the uncontended case, it's just an atomic compare-and-swap to lock and unlock the mutex, just like a spinlock. Only if there is contention, then the thread that wants the lock will do a system call which will put it to sleep, and the kernel will wake it when the lock is released. This is in most cases exactly what you want. Only if you have a lot of lock contention *and* you know that locks will be released very quickly after taking them is it more efficient to use another type of lock.

They are also simpler to reason about because you don't have to worry about dealing with memory ordering/barriers/spinning/waiting.

## Use the C11 thread support library

Since you are using C11's `atomic_int`, then instead of using the POSIX threads API, I recommend that you use the [C11 thread functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) to manage threads.

## Benchmark your code

Try to set up a realistic benchmark, so you can objectively measure the performance.

Comment: Agreed about the busy-loops. An alternative using the C11 standard library is to turn them into idle-loops by inserting a call to `thrd_yield()`. Ad you know, this is close to how a spin lock on a mutex or condition variable would be implemented.

Comment: True. While that helps in a scenario where there are more active threads than CPU cores, if there is nothing available to yield to, it will still unnecessarily use CPU time. An alternative would be to insert something like a [PAUSE instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725676/how-does-x86-pause-instruction-work-in-spinlock-and-can-it-be-used-in-other-sc), which I don't think `thrd_yield()` will do for you.

Comment: I see your point in the special case where there the thread is blocked but has no other active thread to yield to. The solution might be to make your algorithm obstruction-free, so threads only block other threads if they make forward progress. I think it’s pretty rare for a PC not to have any other processes running. But yes, the `mtx_` and `cnd_` wait functions might `pause`on some implementations. I remember complaints about older versions of Linux running down the batteries on people’s laptops because they busy-waited.

Comment: It is actually not rare at all. Check your own PC(s), if not all cores are used 100%, it means there is no active thread to yield to. The problem here is not lock/wait/obstruction-freeness, the problem is just how to wait properly when there is nothing to do.

Comment: For anyone interested in optimizing this: [A really good post with examples and benchmarks of spinlock and mutex implementations.](https://probablydance.com/2019/12/30/measuring-mutexes-spinlocks-and-how-bad-the-linux-scheduler-really-is/) Also some great follow-ups in the comments.

Comment: I did try using posix semaphores before the atomic spinlock. The problem is the overhead for waiting when there is no need to wait is almost tenfold. The system calls do better when the thread should be waiting for a while probably doing sth with the OS scheduler and doesn't waste CPU cycles. For the condition variables, I haven't tested, but from their API structure I believe the overhead won't be less than a semaphore. I wrote this code to minimize the overhead when the thread doesn't have to wait.

Comment: @Davislor If I really don't care about the wasted CPU cycles and all is important is that the waiting time should be as minimal as possible, wouldn't a busy waiting loop be the best solution?

Comment: @Davislor I also read your linked post, but in my code, I didn't use the "terrible" solution by just doing the load for a check in the loop. If two threads are always busy enough, I think the current code has the minimal waiting time.

Comment: I was trying not to say this, but I'm actually a bit annoyed by your answer. Maybe I misunderstood a bit about this community, but your attitude of announcing your subjective opinions as an objective fact is quite annoying to me. If you can provide a better *working* solution, I'll accept it. All you've done is *recommending* condition variables and saying they're *quite* efficient without even testing how much possible overhead they can have.

Comment: @xiver77 This is a bit too complicated to fully answer in comments, but: a busy-wait can perform very badly. The OS can preempt a thread at any time, including during a critical section, where it will block all the other threads. If they’re all busy uselessly spinning, the thread with the lock might never be able to make progress and release it. Or, if an interrupt routine tries to enter the same critical section, it might freeze the system.

Comment: @xiver77 Generally, busy waiting more than a few times is wasteful: the thread hogging the CPU to check the lock uselessly might be preventing another from running and letting it claim the lock sooner. It also might be preempting a thread that needs to play audio, display a frame, process a transaction, or do something else on a tight deadline that it’s required to meet. It will additionally waste electricity.

Comment: And, please, let’s be kind to each other. It’s typical not to post the code of another solution here. The general idea is to give feedback on your code, not to write our own completely different programs. While sometimes that’s a good way to illustrate a point, other times, it isn’t helpful to the OP.

Comment: @Davislor In the posted code at least one thread is always running. The OS could block the running thread preventing the busy waiting thread to claim the lock, but this applies to all other locking mechanisms. But I agree to you that "the thread hogging the CPU to check the lock uselessly might be preventing another from running", so I will test what works best.

Comment: @xiver77 It largely depends on how many threads you have. A spinlock implementation typically wants to have one thread pinned to each core, or so. If that’s how the system is running, spinning uselessly will keep each CPU running at 100%, wasting electricity and raising the temperature, but the CPU would just have been idling anyway. On an Intel CPU with HyperThreading, however, this will actually slow down one other thread, and you want to insert a `_mm_pause()` so the other hardware thread on the same core can progress. Or you might have more threads than cores.

Comment: @Davislor I did some tests with alternative versions using semaphores and condition variables. You can see my recent edit for the results. It also matches a bit with the results from your linked post comparing spinlocks and mutexes since condition variables are based upon mutexes, but the overall winner seems to be semaphores.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Please check the revisions of the question and roll back if necessary to prevent answer invalidation.

Comment: @xiver77 It's not our job to benchmark your code, although we sometimes do that. I've provided you with alternatives, and it seems that has already helped you because now you have tried to compare three different ways to solve your problem. However, talking about objective facts, I did not see any numbers showing just how efficient each implementation is. Also be aware that it will depend as well on the kind of workload you are benchmarking, as well as compiler optimization levels and the platform you are running the benchmarks on.